# How can I find "cpdflib.h"

Tags: c++, c, pdf, ubuntu, build

I'm working under ubuntu 12.04 and try to compile php from the source code.
Here's an issue comes out: cannot find "cpdflib.h"
I search with apt-cache search pdflib, couldn't find anything contains this .h file.
How can I find this header file?

Comment: I believe this question is more fitting at AskUbuntu than here on SO

Comment: Most source bundles have a README that will describe the prerequisites.  Doesn't PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You need **ClibPDF** which can be found [**here**](http://www.fastio.com/).